# Brightness works with Function (FN) Keys in Lubuntu 12.10 but not Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, brightness, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Portege R930 laptop and installed Lubuntu 12.10 through Wubi and then installed the Ubuntu-Desktop package afterwards.

When in Lubuntu, pressing <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> lowers and increases my screen brightness perfectly, however, when logging into Ubuntu (instead of Lubuntu), the function keys don't work.

Ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem with an Asus S200E. Some function  keys (brightness, touchpad-toggle) do not work in Lubuntu. But they do in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

same problem for me, brightness key don't work with the kernel Linux 3.5.0-23-generic.

But when I boot with the Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (with grub, just hold shift key when booting and choose advanced , Linux 3.5.0.17 kernel) everything just work !

as the Linux 3.5.0-17 is the base kernel, you should have it installed and you can try that trick.